# I'm trying to write an API - the expected output

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an API trying to display output based on below code but not getting expected output. here `Bed_Configurations` is a class in which `type,code,count` are parameters.

```
  Bed_Configurations objbed= new Bed_Configurations();
                        objbed.type = "Double";
                        objbed.code = 1;
                        objbed.count = 1;
                        kingroom.bed_configurations = new Bed_Configurations[1];
                        kingroom.bed_configurations[0] = objbed;
```

Expected output:

```
    "bed_configurations": [
                   [{
                     "type": "standard",
                     "code": 3,
                     "count": 1
                     }]
                ],
```

but getting

```
    "bed_configurations": [
                   {
                     "type": "standard",
                     "code": 3,
                     "count": 1
                     }
                ],
```

Please tell me how to add again array brace to hole part

Comment: The real question is, why do you expect your expected output as the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are expecting that "bed_configurations" would result in an array containing arrays of bed_configurations, or if it is really what you want.

What you have created is an array of bed_configurations, and the JSON output reflects exactly that:

[ ] = an array

{ } = an object

Answer (score 0):

```
  Bed_Configurations objbed= new Bed_Configurations();
                    List<Bed_Configurations> objbedL = new List<Bed_Configurations>();
                   List<List<Bed_Configurations>> objbedList = new List<List<Bed_Configurations>>();
                     objbed.type = "double";
                     objbed.code = 1;
                     objbed.count = 1;
                     objbedL.Add(objbed);
                     objbedList.Add(objbedL);
                     kingroom.bed_configurations = new List<List<Bed_Configurations>>();
```